# Multiple uses of "this" keyword in Java

Tags: java

So, I have this. It compares two card decks and if they are the same the result is true.

```
public boolean equals ( Object obj ) {
      boolean result = true;
      for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
          if (this.cardAt(i) = this2.cardlist(i)) {
              result = true;
          } else {
              result = false;
          }
      }
   }
```

I would like to be able to compare two random card decks, if you will.
But I don't know how to compare two different ones using "this . 
I simply wrote "this2" to replace another instance of "this".
What could I do to replace this "this2" to still be able to compare two card decks?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of the code!

Comment: Do you have a class that represents a deck? (Is that what 'this' stands for?) If so, looks like your goal is to implement the equals method for that class.

Comment: @Vance Maverick
yes, that's right!

Comment: Does your `obj` has the instance method `int cardlist(int)` member function ?

Comment: Each deck shouldn't be one object? You are receiving just one object to compare

Comment: @Mahesh
yes,its this. for the sake of the assignment its private.
 private Card [] cardList;

Comment: @Rafael
each deck should be one object. i think the other users cleared it up!

Answer (score 4):

`obj` is your `this2`

Consider this adaptation:

```
public boolean equals ( Object obj) {
      if(!obj instanceof Deck) return false; // make sure you can cast
      Deck otherDeck = (Deck)obj // make the cast
      for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
          if (!this.cardAt(i).equals(otherDeck.cardAt(i)) // use .equals() instead of ==
            return false; // return false on the first one that's wrong
      }
      return true;

 }
```

Your old method would have been flawed. Let's say there's a 4 card deck:
{ 4S, 3C, 5D, AH }
And another 4 card deck
{ 4S, 10C, 5D, AH}

Walk through them

```
result = true
current index 0... compare 4S to 4S... good, so...
result = 4S == 4S ? true
result = 3C == 10C ? false
result = 5D == 5D ? true
result = AH == AH ? true
```

So your method only tests if the LAST card is correct. (Also it never returns when you're done!)

Comment: Yeah, things can be tricky. Even simple things, you have to walk through them carefully sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You would cast obj to the type of class you are currently in, like so

```
MyClass other = (MyClass)obj;
// Now do calculations using  other  instead of  this2.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals ( Object obj )
{
     boolean result = false; // No need of result variable
     for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
         if (this.cardAt(i) == obj.cardlist(i)) // not = , it should be ==
         {
              return true;
         } 
     }
     return false;
}
```

**Edit 1:** However, this logic do not traverse the entire `cardlist`. Just tests whether the corresponding cards are equal or not. If found at least one match, it returns leaving the rest of cards to be compared, else traverses the entire list.

Comment: No need for the whole `result` variable.